# Christofides algorithm: why must an MST have even number of odd-degree vertices?

Tags: graphs, minimum-spanning-tree

This question is not necessarily related to [Christofides algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christofides_algorithm) per se, I just ran into it when reading about it.

I assume that a minimum spanning tree must have an even number of odd-degree vertices, since Christofides algorithm uses this fact to find a perfect matching between "the set of vertices with odd degree in $T$" - an impossible mission for a graph with odd number of vertices...

I couldn't convince myself why this is true, can someone please convince me? Either by a formal proof or with an informal explanation.

Comment: A graph can have an "odd number of vertices", but not an odd number of vertices with odd degree. $\hspace{.48 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer, what I meant there is that a graph with an odd number of vertices in it cannot have perfect matching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every edge in a graph is incident with exactly two vertices. The degree of a vertex is the number of edges incident with it. From this you get the standard fact that the sum of all the vertex degrees in a graph equals twice the number of edges; in particular, it is even. A minimum spanning tree is a graph in its own right. If it had an odd number of odd-degree vertices, the sum of degrees would be odd, which is impossible.